# Objects with fixed values

Tags: java, class, object

I am developing a game. I have a class weapon and different sub classes like `Shotgun`, `Mg`...
Now i want to have specific weapons like AK47 with 30 bullets ammo 10 points of dmg etc.
The same thing is with class car. A Lamborghini for example has a fixed max speed of 300 km/h while a Seat leon has fixed max speed of 200 but is still a car (or subclass?).
How should i do that? Is Lamborghini a subclass of car with fixed values in constructor? Should i have constants for values of every car in car class or in a file?
Hope i am clear enough.
Thanks

EDIT:
I think i was not clear enough. I Need to "save" default values of the cars (Lamborghini: max peed 300...) so that in game a Player can have that Lamborghini and it has always max Speed 300. The Option with the subclass falls away now because a Lamborghini is just a Instance of car. So my Question now: In a File or as static constants in class car?
For example:

```
public class car  {
   public static final int SPEED_LAMBORGHINI = 300

   // rest of class car
}
```

I think a file would be better design but doesn't it take to Long to load every needed weapon from a file?

Comment: It's completely up to you where to store these values. If you are certain these values will never change, you can go with hardcoded values. Otherwise go with some external file. I don't think reading some values from the file would take that long.

Comment: I have seen that this question is a bit opinion based. But if we put together all the answers we have a good answer for future. I can't answer my own question because i am new. Also i can't upvote at the Moment. But if someone wants to make a summary i will mark that as the right answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have seen that this the answer to this question depends on the own opinion and on the design of the game. No answer is realy the right answer so i decided to write a summary:

- If your objects (cars, weapons etc.) have the same functionalities and fields there is no Need for a subclass.
- To safe your fixed values you can write them in external Files and read them when needed.
- You can also store them in your source-code as final Constants or as Enums.
- You also can have a Constructor of car or whatever you Need with a int typ as Parameter. Depending on this type you can use the right constants for your object.
- If you Need many objects with the same typ and values you can also implement a copy-method and load all the different types on Startup (but think about the Memory they take), and then copy them when needed.

Hope this helps you and thanks for your answers (:

Comment: Can you please explain why you downvoted the answer? I don't care about the vote but if you tell me why i can improve the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Generally a *Lamborghini* would be a `Car` with a `name` field of type `String` with value "Lamborghini" and a `maxSpeed` field of type `int` and value `300`.

I guess the rest becomes obvious.

Essentially - use a different class for a different `Form` of object. You rarely need every object having a different class.

A *DeLorean* would be a `Car` but a Time Travelling *DeLorean* might be a different class.

However - since `enum`s are now available you may wish to consider:

```
enum Car {
    Lamborghini(300),
    Seat(200);

    final int topSpeed;

    private Car(int topSpeed) {
        this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
    }
}
```

**Added**

As to your query about where to store teh details - I would put defaults in the code but allow each object to modify that value from say a properties file. An `enum` helps a great deal here as you can put something like:

```
TopSpeed.Lamborghini=286
```

in your properties file and get the `enum` to automagically adjust it.

**Added**

Remember that `enum`s are meant to be as close to constants as you can achieve. Do not attempt to extend them or change their properties (except perhaps once at the start).

To use this form you will need something like:

```
class Player {
  Car vehicle = Lamborghini;
  ...
```

Comment: @RossDrew - Then you would factor out the `Headlights` of the `Car` into a new `class` and allow each car type to pick it's own `Headlight` type.

Comment: Accidentally deleted my comment :/.  So yes, in order to add a car with special headlights you would need to modify the car.  Violating the open-closed principle.

Comment: @RossDrew - Please explain what this "Open-Closed" principle is. I don't see how this design is any more unstable than any other. All designs are brittle to some form of change.

Comment: It's not unstable, it's perfectly usable.  I just don't think it complies with SOLID principles http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle

Comment: @RossDrew No, OldCurmudgeon is right. There is always some feature for which you can say "But this design doesn't allow changing X." His proposed solution allows arbitrary headlights to be added to cars without changing the source code for Car. That's exactly what the Open/Closed Principle says. It need not allow switching any other car part until the OP knows that's a requirement.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon As i am now thinking of using enums i have the following questions: If i am using enum Car i have to but all the getters and setters and the constructor into the enum right? Also i can't have subclasses of car when i use enum? And the last question: If two players have a `Car car = Car.Lamborghini;` will they both have the same car or 2 cars with the same properties?

Comment: @Springrbua - The `enum` must only maintain constant data. You will need `class Player { final Car vehicle = Car.Lamborghini;` or similar. No you cannot sub-class `Car` or `Lamborghini` for similar reasons. Yes the two cars would be the same - even to the point that `player1.vehicle == player2.vehicle` will work as expected

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon so i can't use Enums... I liked the solution but in this case it won't work. I think i will use .xml files to store the data. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You should differentiate between what is a *class* and what is an *instance*

A Lamborgini for example is still of the class *car*, but it's a special instance. The **Class** itself should contain informations about the **structure** of any instance (i.e. a Car has a NAME and a TOPSPEED).

Then, when creating an Instance, you should specify those defined attributes.

```
Car Lamorgini = new Car("Lamborgini", 300);
Car Seat = new Car("Seat", 200);
```

This would also allow to save all the Instance information out of your "code" in order to easy implement new carinstances, without rebuilding your application.

Comment: The Thing is that i will use the same values over and over. When i use your patern i can define that a Lamborghini has 200 top Speed etc. So i nedd to safe the cartypes default values somewhere.

Comment: @user3182091 This is how it works. Ofc. in practice you would define a "id" for tha car and load ALL values depending on id (thus seperating the MODEL and the DATA). Say "Porsche 911" is your id , and your dataset holds information about horse power, wheels, color, etc) - using a method to load your car will insert all information then. (`CarService->loadCar("Porsche 911 Turbo")`

Comment: @user3182091 Apparently you can use CarModel class to hold make, top speed etc. and Car class to hold color and other instance-specific properties.

Answer (score 1):

Each car type can simply be an instance from the class `Car`, with fields such as `carName`, `topSpeed`, etc, being settable for each particular type. Conceptually too, Lamborghini or other cars don't have any attributes too different from any other car, so it's not really necessary for different cars to be subclasses of `Car`. You can have the different fields settable from the `Car` constructor and/or from setter methods, such as `setTopSpeed()` or `setName()` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

In my game I used XML "profiles" which defined properties of concrete object.
It was useful for me because it allowed game designed, who is different person, easily change those values without need to deal with code directly. Also it is easy to add new types of weapons/cars/... without programming anything.

But your approach is ok too. It is more or less matter of common sense and taste.

Comment: This is exactly what i need because i want to add new Weapons later. Also new Weapon types but this then are subclasses. So the question now is: Constantsin class or a file. Isn't it much Trouble loading the files always when you Need new weapon/car?
Do you have a file for every car/weapon or 1 file for all of them?

Comment: I had them in different files. You can create factory which loads all the profiles once and then you can instantiate a type of weapon you need by a name of profile.

Comment: So if i start my game with my character Holding an AK47 i just load the AK47.xml (or whatever) and create an instance of weapon out of this Information?

Comment: Something like that. It can even bring more benefit if you have some scripting in your game. You can refer to these profiles by their names.

Comment: Well i could also "link" to this file by having a hashmap or something like this with a int typ as key and String path as value?
Or is that a bad Thing?

Comment: There is number of solutions you can use. You can add method clone to your object which would create copy of the original object. So, you load your objects once and when you need some type of object you get it from hash map by name and clone it.

Comment: In your oppinion are the preferences of libgdx (i am using libgdx) also a good way to manage that. It generates an XML file and you dont have to manage the path etc. You can simply getPreference("PreferenceName") and then you can use getBoolean("key", "defaultValue"), the same with float etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the different cars and weapons have different functionalities I think it's better to stick to the classes `Car` and `Weapon`.

Just have a field like `weaponType` or `weaponName` to distinguish between different weapons.

Comment: Except for if you need to distinguish between different weapons then they probably should go to different classes.

Comment: Yea Weapons have subclasses like Shotgun and Sniper but this subclasses have a Special Instance like an AWM Sniper is always the same AWM sniper. And the same is with the cars then...

Answer (score 1):

That is actually not an easy question to answer, as it is a design decision without a clear correct answer but I will try to help as best as I can.

However you design your code in the end, it has to be consistent, so it would be a good approach to have a rule when to subclass and when not to. A good rule for this would be to subclass only if the behaviour changes.

In your example, if the only difference between a Lamborghini and a Toyota is its speed, color and name and your `Car`-class already has fields `speed`, `color` and `name` there is no reason to have subclasses for Lamborghinis and Toyotas.

A tank for example is a typical subclass of a `Car`, as it certainly has a name, speed and color but behaves quite differently, will very likely need a set of new methods unrelated to `Car`s (like shooting) and might behave differently (for example a `Car`is destroyed when its `accident(Car other)` method gets called, a tank would still implement this method but behave differently).

So try to think if your subclass actually behaves different from its parent to determine if it is worth an own class.

Answer (score 0):

Have an abstract class `Car` that calls it's own abstract method `getTopSpeed()` which is overridden and implemented by sub classes `Lamborghini` and `Seat Leon`.

This means that you could just get a `Car` from any method or collection and access it's top speed without even knowing what kind of car it is. It's called polymorphism.

Comment: So the subclasses have fixed values inside getTopSpeed() ?

Comment: I don't think it's good idea. Would you create subclass for every student in a group for example? Same situation here.

Comment: No, it's not because every student has the same properties and actions so they would use one class. `Student` may however be a sub class of, say, `Person`

Comment: Then you may have `CSStudent` as a subclass of `Student` they would have all the actions of a student but perhaps additional ones specific to CS.

Comment: @RossDrew for given data all cars have same properties either.

Comment: @user3182091 the sub classes could have fixed values yes, if you had private variables that contained those values and return them with `@getTopSpeed()`

Comment: Which is basically like saying all shapes have the same properties so why do we subclass `Shape` with `Square`, `Circle`, etc?

Comment: @RossDrew I strongly doubt all shapes share the same properties. Circle has radius, rectangle has length and width. People tend to calculate their area using different formulas.

Comment: @RossDrew the cars or in my case weapons (i used cars for better explaining) have the same properties. Nothing less nothing more but just fixed values for those properties. If they had more properties ofc i would use subclasses

Answer (score 0):

"Is lamborghini a subclass of car with fixed values in constructor?"

Possibly. Or just a car with values that you set in the constructor and never reset. Or maybe just a car with initial values; damage might reduce that maximum, for example. Depends on the needs of your program and on how/whether you're going to expose this class for manipulation and reuse.

"Should i have constants for values of every car in car class or in a file?"

One or the other, certainly.